# Which type of programs perform address binding at compile time and load time

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

I was reading a book on operating systems and i got a doubt on when compile time and load time address bindings are used in modern computing devices. With multiprogramming and swapping to disk memory, I doubt if such conecepts are still relevant in 2023.

I assume that kernel programs can generate load time address binding, but rigt now I can think of no use case for when compile time bindings are actually used.

Can anyone please clear my doubt.